# duplicate names are being created even when I choose an option from the predefined dropdown list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

Hi all I am trying to use Ruby on Rails Devise to create a new Company that a User belongs_to. While I am able to create associated company objects (under fields_for), new company objects with duplicate names are being created even when I choose an option from the predefined dropdown list. By right I should be able to select the option from the dropdown list. How can I amend my codes such that I can select and use an option from the dropdown list instead of creating a new object with duplicate names?

My codes are as shown below:-

```
#new.html.erb

<% resource.build_company %>
<%= form_for resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), :html => {class: "ui small form"} do |f| %>

   <%= f.fields_for :company do |builder| %>
     <%= builder.select :name, Company.all.collect{ |p| [p.name, p.id] }, {prompt: "Company"}, :class => "company_options ui fluid search selection dropdown"  %>
   <%end%>

<%= f.submit "Sign up" %>

#companies_controller.rb

class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  before_action :configure_sign_up_params, only: [:create]

  protected

  def configure_sign_up_params
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:lastname, :firstname,company_attributes:[:name]])
  end
end

#user.rb

class User < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :company  
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :company
end


#company.rb

class Company < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :users
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of building a new company and accepting nested attributes for the new company, just allow to choose a `company_id`:

```
# in your view
<%= f.collection_select :company_id, Company.all, :id, :name %>

# in your controller
def configure_sign_up_params
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:lastname, :firstname, :company_id])
end
```

And remove the `accepts_nested_attributes_for :company` line from your `User` model.

Comment: hey spickerman, thanks for the reply! If i want to have the option to add a new company if company does not exist, else choose a company from the predefined dropdown list, how would I amend the codes accordingly?

Comment: @KengHong: Please ask a new question with the changed or extended requirements. Because the original question is solved. And a new question will get more attention from other readers than this comments.